# Image Height: 100% in a grid. Safari vs Firefox. Why does Safari default images to the viewheight?

Tags: css, image, safari, height, css-grid

hyhy, I've started a website and designed it for Firefox, but did the rounds and found Safari was not treating images in the same way. I'm running into issues with Safari making every single image's height the same as the browser's viewheight/viewport height. [Here is a dummy site](http://gvg.gg/gvgtest.github.io/aboutest.html) that you can pull up a version in Firefox and Safari to compare.

I'm running a 15 column grid without an exact column width (1 fr is used) or row height (min-content is used). In Firefox, the browser finds the width of the image based on how many columns the image spans out of the 15 total columns, and then proportionately sets the image's height. In Safari, the image has the same height as the browser window itself with no regard for how much of the width of the photo is cutoff and the extra burden of scrolling caused by this behavior.

**Solutions attempted so far**:

- *Defining a max row height:* This solution gives Safari a pixel dimension to scale my image to and things behave correctly on images. However, the accordion at the bottom of the page has too much content when open, and not much content when closed, which requires a dynamic min-content sizing approach. When applying a maximum row height to my grid (example: grid-auto-rows: 175px;), the accordion's content extends past the grid. The result is the content of my accordion is not respected, the grid ends too soon and my footer inserts itself while the rest of my content balloons out the bottom of the page.
- *Define each image's px height in css:* This solution just changes how the website looks in Firefox, with images not filling up the vertical spaces they need to.
- *Define each image's height as less than 100% of its parent element:* This does indeed make the images smaller in Safari, since the browsers reads height: 100% and defaults to the browser's viewport height. However, this clearly breaks in Firefox and images fill less than 100% of the defined Row span.

This grid system is used all over my website, which is very photograph-forward. I'd love to not define a max row height, but Safari seems to be desperate for a defined row height but not want to do it the way Firefox does.

My hope? Some sort of minmax(min-content, defined-value) replacement that let's me have rows with zero content have zero height, rows with lots of content have matching height to that content and still have a 'default'? value for images to get their sizes from? What can I do here to get the look of the Firefox version to show up on Safari?

Comment: which css reset are you using? which informations do code inspectors give you?

Comment: Just these three: 
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}